# tail recursion again (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

I implemented tail recursion..since tail recursion is really challenging.. I couldn't figure out clearly.. so the best way, maybe try several implementations until it become clear.. so...here is my code..

```
tail recursion practice
(define (tstFunc lst1 lst2)
 (define (tstFunc-helper ls1 ls2 rst)
   (if (or (null? ls1) (null? ls2))
       rst
       (tstFunc-help (cdr ls1) (cdr lst2) 
                (cons (tstFunc lst1 lst2) rst)))))
```

I can't find what is wrong. can someone point out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is:

```
(define (tstFunc lst1 lst2)    ;                                           0
  (define (tstFunc-helper      ; helper function                           1
                 ls1           ; its 1st argument  <-----------------\     2
                 ls2           ;     2nd argument  <--------------\  |     3
                 result )      ;     3rd argument                 |  |     4
                                        ;                         |  |     5
     (if (or (null? ls1) (null? ls2))   ;                         |  |     6
        result                          ; return result, OR       |  |     7
        (tstFunc-help                   ; call self with          |  |     8
             (cdr ls1)                  ;   as the next 'ls1' ----|--/     9
             (cdr lst2)                 ;   as the next 'ls2' ----/       10
             (cons                      ;   as the next 'result'          11
                  (tstFunc lst1 lst2)   ; prefix this value (*)           12
                  result)               ;   to current "result", to       13
                                        ;   construct the next "result"   14
             )))                        ;                                 15
                                        ;                                 16
  )
```

You define a helper function *(1)*, but don't call it *(16)*. A typical initial call will use some initial "result" value, like `'()` for list construction.

You refer to arguments to the outer function, in your inner function *(10,12)*. It is allowed, just highly probably not what you intended - in particular, `lst2` "as the next 'ls2'" won't ever change, will always be the same list.

You're combining your lists *(12)* at each step by calling the main function *(0)*, creating infinite recursion. You should use some 3rd function to combine them. Usually we combine the `car`s of our lists, but sometimes the lists themselves are needed too, that's not the problem. But again you're using the wrong argument names there.

Since you build the result by consing *(11)*, you probably want to return the final result *(7)* reversed back into the original order.

Comment: It helped me to see clearly my problem with tail recursion. thx

Answer (score 0):

Will's code does not work. He does not call the helper function. Also when he calls it inside the recursion he uses the wrong name. This code does work, although you don't specify what kind or result you want.

```
 (define (tstFunc lst1 lst2)

  (define (tstFunc-helper      ; helper function
                 ls1           ; its 1st argument  <-----------------\
                 ls2           ;     2nd argument  <--------------\  |
                 result )      ;     3rd argument                 |  |
                                        ;                         |  |
     (if (or (null? ls1) (null? ls2))   ;                         |  |
        result                          ; return result, OR       |  |
        (tstFunc-helper                 ; call self with          |  |
             (cdr ls1)                  ;   as the next 'ls1' ----|--/
             (cdr ls2)                  ;   as the next 'ls2' ----/
             (cons                      ;   as the next 'result'
          (cons ls1 ls2)     ; prefix this value (*)
          result)            ;   to current "result", to
                             ;     construct the next "result"
             )))
  (tstfunc-helper lst1 lst2 '()))`
```

This is Will's version modified to call the helper function, and with the name fixed. 
Edit: I fixed the variable names. Didn't see them the first time.

Comment: guys, (a) it says so at the beginning of my answer that it is *not* *my* code, right; and (b) this code here still has  errors as I've described in my answer. The point is not to give the corrected code, but to explain what's wrong with the original so the OP can fix it, to learn better.

Comment: @user1915570 `(cons(cons lst1 lst2) result)` is still wrong. you should reference `ls1` and `ls2` there too.

Comment: @Will Ness, yes,I totally agree with you, thx, for pointing that out too. but don't worry for this question, I did figure out based on your explanation before this answer posted. I could see that your "don't call it" part from your answer. so I got it myself. and I also found out that the code should be like this...(cdr ls1) (cdr ls2) (cons(cons ls1 ls2 result).. before (cdr ls1) (cdr lst2) and yes, that also I saw it.. that was wrong too and even added to make right order part as well  in my code. now I have much better and clear understanding about tail recursion and this code. appreciate!

Comment: yes, I know, I did all and it worked all correctly with the output result which I wanted. (all worked before this answer that I saw) :-) otherwise, I probably asked you with additional comments.

Comment: Well, I don't have enough reputation to comment your answer Will, that's why I posted another one. I didn't understand why you gave non-working code in you answer. Thanks for pointing my errors out, I fixed my code to include your comment.

Comment: @Rptx I posted the OP's code, commenting on their errors, just as was asked in the question: "I can't find what is wrong. can someone point [it] out?". :)